# How do I reference a Razor variable later in my page in JavaScript or HTML

Tags: javascript, razor

I have the following Razor code:

```
@{
    if (IsPost)
    {
        string pn=Request.Form["pn"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pn)){
            /* my code to call the stored procedure with pn as a parameter*/
        }
    }
}
```

And in the page, using JavaScript / HTML I need to tell the user about `pn`. Be it that it's empty, or report back that the value was inserted in the database.

How do I do that?

Comment: Calling a stored procedure directly from a view is not good practice. You should call the stored procedure from your controller and pass the result to your view through a model.

Comment: I wish I knew what controllers and views are... I'm just getting started with this paradigm of programming. I'll keep your advice in mind for when I get a yellow belt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to insert the result into the rendering. There are a couple of ways of doing that. You could store it in a variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pn = '@(pn)';
    alert('pn is ' + pn);
</script>
```

Or you could call a function, sort of like JSONP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    parsePn('@(pn)');
    <!-- ... extra logic ...  --> 
    function parsePn(pn) {
        alert('pn is ' + pn);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but in which part of it? I tried both inside a `<div>` and inside the `@{ }` block and both throw errors - `The name 'pn' does not exist in the current context`

.

Comment: It's working now. It's that the first time this page is loaded (not coming from a form submit) `IsPost` is false, and the variable `pn` was non-existent. Thanks.